# Logger path on server beside the project path

Tags: java, web-services, log4j

i have web service project and would like to get the root path of my project to define the logger file path related to project path... 
i know this part of code and i don't know if it working will or not ... ?

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    ServletContext context = event.getServletContext();
    System.setProperty("rootPath", context.getRealPath("../Logs/"));
}
```

then the logger part of code

`log4j.appender.file.File=${rootPath}WEB-INF/logs/TecnichalLog.log
 log4j.appender.file.File=${rootPath}WEB-INF/logs/PerformanceLog.log`

note : i'm using embeded tomcat so i couldn't use `${catalina.base}` ...

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use relative paths from within the project. The path would be relative to the folder from where tomcat is started. Usually /bin/.
Or if you know your runtime environment and it is consistent across all nodes, then there is nothing wrong in using absolute paths.

Comment: i'm using embedded tomcat and also the project will move to many different environment , that why i would to declare the path using context ...

Comment: Ok, The property rootPath is only available during runtime. So you could programatically set the log4j appenders after that. You could configure a console appender until this point so that you won't loose the startup logs.

Comment: No! i can write the property when ever i want **But** the problem is the project will be deployed by other person who will only deploy without editing and XML file or and properties, the only thing i can do is to tell him that the project will generate Log.file near the war file ...

Comment: Thats not what i meant. Absolute or relative path, statically configured or programatically, in any case you'll have to define a folder within the tomcat/server installation as the folder for logs. If you have one already, use it otherwise you may have to discuss and confirm the path to this folder with your system administrators.